# $\ell$-adic schematic homotopy type

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homotopy-theory, l-adic-sheaves

In the groundbreaking paper [Champs Affines](https://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/%7Ebtoen/chaff.pdf) ([DOI](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00029-006-0019-z)), Toen constructs a generalisation of rational homotopy types which he calls *schematic homotopy types.* This is part of a larger
programme of a theory developed in Toen's [Homotopy types of algebraic varieties](https://perso.math.univ-toulouse.fr/btoen/files/2015/02/AIM.pdf) (different to motivic homotopy theory), which, to my knowledge, has not been carried out in full.

One particular direction suggested in sections 3.5.2 and 3.5.3 of [Champs Affines](https://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/%7Ebtoen/chaff.pdf) is the development of a theory of crystalline and $\ell$-adic homotopy types.

The first has been developed by Ollson in [$F$-isocrystals and homotopy types](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Emolsson/FHomotopy.pdf) ([DOI](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jpaa.2006.10.006)).

Has any work been published in the $\ell$-adic direction?

More generally has any more of Toen's programme been worked out in the literature?

Answer (score 1):

Étale homotopy type of scheme is rather classical object, see original Artin–Mazur paper or/and Quillen works on Adams conjecture with brilliant lectures of Sullivan "geometric topology" on the same topic, where localization and completion of homotopy type were first described.

Comment: This begs the question of what is the relation between etale and schematic homotopy types. The original question is about the latter.

Comment: I was sure that they coincide, and that may be the case. There are papers by Gereon Quick on section conjecture, where the same statement as in Toen's one made.